# Solr DataImportHandler incorrect Oracle date in index

Tags: oracle, solr, indexing, timezone, dataimporthandler

I use Solr 3.4 to index field retrieved from oracle 10 database by DataImportHandler. Oracle field of type "DATE" has value: 2011-09-20. Solr index field of type "solr.TrieDateField" has value 2011-09-19T22:00:00Z. My (oracle, solr, windows) timezone is GMT+1. I expected to have solr index field value: 2011-09-19T23:00:00Z. Why it's not?

Config:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:***" user="" password="" />
    <document>
        <entity name="event" query="select start_date from event" >
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I use ojdbc14 version 11.2.0.2

Solr admin -> java properties -> user.timezone = Europe/Belgrade (which is GMT+1)

After research I've found possible cause:

```
select DBTIMEZONE, SESSIONTIMEZONE from dual;
1. +2:00 +01:00
```

Is solr using dbtimezone instead of sessiontimezone?

I've found the answer:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(timestamp '2011-08-20 00:00:00', 'CET') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' from dual;
11/08/19 22:00:00,000000000 GMT
SELECT FROM_TZ(timestamp '2011-12-20 00:00:00', 'CET') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' from dual;
11/12/19 23:00:00,000000000 GMT
```

First date includes Daylight Saving Time, second does not. So obvious.

Comment: Did you found an solution to solve this problem ?